# How to navigate to next data record from database using data reader? vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, sqlcommand, datareader

I would like to create a button which allow me to navigate to next data record and show in textbox.

here is my current code which can only show the first record in textbox.

```
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    cmd.Connection = Conn
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT sendby,enquiry,status FROM Message WHERE recipient LIKE '" & namelbl.Text & "'"

    Dim dr As SqlDataReader
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader


    If dr.HasRows Then

        dr.Read()
        form.Label2.Text = dr.Item("sendby")
        form.Label4.Text = dr.Item("enquiry")

        form.Label6.Text = dr.Item("status")

        dr.Close()

    End If
    Conn.Close()
```

So how can i do to show different row data in textbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should allow you to loop through a `DataReader`

```
Do While dr.Read
    ' Work with items inside loop
Loop
If dr.IsClosed = False Then
    dr.Close()
End If
```

Comment: could you explain more? I can not really get how this loop actually works.

Comment: `ExecuteReader` populates a `SqlDataReader` with a forward only, read only retrieval of your SQL query.  The Do-Loop iterates over each record in your query, allowing you to act upon each record.

Comment: thanks for your explaination now i got what you mean!By the way how if i want to navigate to the previous record?

Comment: If you need to go forward and backward, you'll want to look into a `DataSet`.  Here's an example site: http://vb.net-informations.com/dataset/dataset-sqlserver.htm

Keep in mind that there's additional overhead on the server for using a DataSet since it must keep the entire resultset in memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like the following

```
  While dr.Read
        form.Label2.Text = dr.Item("sendby")
        form.Label4.Text = dr.Item("enquiry")
        form.Label6.Text = dr.Item("status")
        dr.Close()
  Wend
  Conn.Close()
```